# Anchor Point Moving Too Far After Direct Selection in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, anchor-point

There seems to be some kind of glitch going on here, or maybe I need to reset my settings. When I use the direct selection tool to select the anchor point of a shape, and then press right or left only *once*, the anchor point moves very far over to the right or to the left:

[image]

[image]

^ that is only after one keystroke. What can I do here to get the movements of the direct selection tool back to normal? I'm seeing some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2qpL5y7-zc&t=26s) out there on how to *use* the direct selection tool but not how to reset it, if that's what the issue is here.

Also Command + Shift + B doesn't do anything for me:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Sorry.  Try [resetting your preferrences](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/how-to-reset-illustrator-preferences/m-p/10602277)

Comment: Check grid, zoom, used units and the preferences for nudge size

Comment: `Preferences > General > Keyboard increments`

Comment: @Scott Yeah my Keyboard increments were set to 18 inches lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of "**nudge**" or distance used when tapping arrow keys is controlled in the Illustrator **preferences**.

`Illustrator > Preferences > General` 
Check the `Keyboard Increments` setting. 
*This is the nudge distance.*

It would appear to me, that you simply have a large nudge setting in place.